# bWAPP on my live webserver is tossing me an sql error

Tags: apache, security, webserver

I am trying to put bWAPP on my spare webserver for me and my friends to use.
It's locked by a password and stuff, so only people who know it can use it.
Here's the configuration I have right now.

```
$db_server = "atroxis.net";
$db_username = "ethereal_atrox";
$db_password = "(redacted)";
$db_name = "ethereal_bwapp";
```

The password is right, I just redacted it.
I keep getting this SQL error.

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'ethereal_atrox'@'51.38.85.24' (using password: YES)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Still looking! If anyone knows, I'll gladly take.

Comment: The reason can be different. The first one that I will check is to see if the user ethereal_atrox has rights to access this database. the simple test is to try to connect from console and run simple sql query

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
$db_server = "localhost";
```

and reload apache.
If it doesn't work, verify the file *connect.php* and change myql_ for **mysqli**_